# cscope Vim plugin: uses tags from multiple repositories?

Tags: vim, cscope

I'm currently using [this](http://cscope.sourceforge.net/cscope_maps.vim) Vim plugin for cscope. It works great, except... it appears to be using tags from multiple directories.

I have two repo's: projectA and projectB. ProjectB has projectA added as a submodule (but it does not have the cscope.out file in it, because it is not added to the repo).

When I put my cursor in thisfunction() in a file in the folder of projectA and press ctlr-G to jump to it, it gives me two options:

```
1   src/myfile.c <<thisfunction>>
2   /home/myname/projectB/submodule/src/myfile.c <<thisfunction>>
```

I have no clue how this is possible. They are in two entirely different folders. Does Vim keep a global cache of cscope files it has found maybe?

How can I fix this?

Comment: Where, exactly, is the `cscope.out` file? What command did you do to generate it and from where? Was `ProjectA` there at that time?

Comment: @romainl both ProjectA and ProjectB have a `cscope.out` file in the root directory of the repository. Both of the files were generated with `cscope -bR`. 
ProjectA is included as a submodule in ProjectB, yes. But it's not in that folder the issue occurs (because then it would make sense). It is in the separate folder ProjectA, outside of folder projectB that the issue occurs.

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the submodule of ProjectB does not have the local copy of projectA linked as a remote. ProjectA pushes to a git server, the submodule follows that master.

Comment: What is the output of `:cscope show`?

Comment: @romainl /home/myname/projectA/cscope.out  (In folder of ProjectA)

Comment: Do you still have the same outcome when using cscope directly, outside of Vim? Do you also have a `tags` file?

Comment: @romainl I don't have the behavior outside of Vim, and yes I also have a `tags` file.
I'm not sure if the problem has resolved itself, but it appears that way. I haven't noticed double entries for the past few hours, even though I didn't change anything afaik.

Comment: That's because you talked to me, obviously ;-).

Comment: Thanks for talking to me in that case! :) 
I'm curious if it will come back though. I've had similar behavior last week. I had duplicate entries of the same repo then.